# Pandas: ValueError parsing UNIX timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, datetime-format

I have a CSV of OHLC data that is indexed by seconds since the epoch:
[image: tabulated CSV data]

I am parsing it thus:

```
df = pd.read_csv(f"{CSV}/{filename}", sep=",", header=0, index_col=0, parse_dates=['time'], date_format='s')
```

However the timestamps are not being parsed to dates:

```
df.index

Index([ 378943200,  379548000,  380152800,  380757600,  381362400,  381967200,
        382572000,  383176800,  383781600,  384386400,
       ...
       1687726800, 1688331600, 1688936400, 1689541200, 1690146000, 1690750800,
       1691355600, 1691960400, 1692565200, 1693170000],
      dtype='int64', name='time', length=2172)
```

Furthermore, if I manually try to convert the index to datetime, I get a ValueError:

```
pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='s', utc=True)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[71], line 1
----> 1 pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='s', utc=True)

...

ValueError: time data "378943200" doesn't match format "s", at position 0. You might want to try:
    - passing `format` if your strings have a consistent format;
    - passing `format='ISO8601'` if your strings are all ISO8601 but not necessarily in exactly the same format;
    - passing `format='mixed'`, and the format will be inferred for each element individually. You might want to use `dayfirst` alongside this.
```

This is a value UNIX timestamp according to [www.unixtimestamp.com](http://www.unixtimestamp.com), so what gives?

Comment: Are you working on data from 1982? Not sure `%s` is a thing here when parsing. The [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) suggest you should use `origin='unix'` here.

Comment: That appears to assume `ns`, so everything comes out as `1970-01-01...`

Comment: The docs do explain you can use `unit='s'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify seconds with `unit`, not `format`

```py
pd.to_datetime(df.index, unit='s', utc=True)
```

Format is for parsing [strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Tester:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"time": [ 378943200,  379548000,  380152800,  380757600,  381362400,  381967200,
        382572000,  383176800,  383781600,  384386400,]})

df["time_dt"] = pd.to_datetime(df["time"], unit="s", utc=True)
print(df.head(3))

# OUT
        time                   time_dt
0  378943200 1982-01-03 22:00:00+00:00
1  379548000 1982-01-10 22:00:00+00:00
2  380152800 1982-01-17 22:00:00+00:00
```

**One-liner with read_csv**

Since `date_parser` [was deprecated in pandas 2.0 (due to performance?)](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/50601), they suggest to use `parse_dates` and `date_format` instead. To my understanding, [since `date_format` uses `strftime` parsing](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/54705/files) and that [doesn't have a flag for unix time](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes), there is no "smart" way to do it, so using `to_datetime` after `read_csv` is probably the way to go (as of pandas 2.1.0).

That being said, you can still pass a custom `converters` for columns, but I have no idea what kind of performance it has compared to `to_datetime` after `read_csv` -method

```py
import io
import datetime
import pandas as pd

csv_file = io.StringIO("time\n378943200\n379548000\n380152800\n")

df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, converters={"time": lambda s: datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(s))})
print(df.time)
```

Comment: This does indeed work for `pd.to_datetime`. Do you have any idea what the shorthand is to get `pd.read_csv` to work similarly in 2.0.x?

Comment: Ok, looks like they could tidy this up then. Have marked as answer. Cheers.